# how to convert @"2016-03-15 01:12:30" to NSDate and calculate difference of that date with the current date?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have used this code but output date is not correct.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSDate * currDate = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Sigh.  How did you output it?

Comment: issue is my (date) variable is in not correct format its showing me different date with UTC time zone.

Comment: About hundred answers will tell your NSDate is completely fine, but you need to understand how NSDate works. If you added the output we could tell you where you live :-)

Comment: Yeah that happens if you simply print it using `NSLog()` (many many questions about this on this site).  Also I doubt you want `hh` but `HH` in the format.

Comment: how many times is such question raised?

Comment: Check relevant questions before asking a question to avoid messing up the community while perfect answers already exist for particular problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code which uses for date difference.

Main problem is your date format causes the problem i.e 'hh' replace with 'HH'.

```
NSString *pastDate=@"2016-03-15 01:12:30";
NSDateFormatter *dateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *datefor=[dateformat dateFromString:pastDate];
NSString *dateStr=[dateformat stringFromDate:datefor];
NSDate *datetype=[dateformat dateFromString:dateStr];



NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components;
NSInteger days;
components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                             fromDate: datetype toDate: currentDate options: 0];
days = [components day];
 NSLog(@"There are %ld days in between the two dates.", (long)days);
```

May this helps.